# Need some German help for logic lemma

Tags: logic

[image]

Ich gucke mir die  folgende Regel an:

[image]

Angenommen ich habe jetzt eine Falsifikation $\frak{I}$ der zweiten $\Gamma,\vartheta\Rightarrow \Delta$ Prämisse. Es muss gelten, dass $\frak{I}(\vartheta)=1$ gilt. Wenn $\frak{I}$ eine Falsifikation für die Konklusion sein will dann muss u.a. $\frak{I}(\psi)=1$ sein, da $\frak{I}$ ein Modul für die Verundung der Antekdenz der Konklusion sein muss. Woher wissen wir das so eine Erweiterung für $\frak{I}$ immer in diesem Fall existiert? Das Lemma besagt nur, dass wenn man eine Falsifikation einer Prämisse hat kann man sie so erweitern das diese Interpretaion eine Falsifikation für dir Konklusion ist. Wenn wir aber unsere Falsifikation nehmen für die zweite Prämisse und sie dann beliebig erweitern und wir auch annehmen, das diese Interpretation dann kein Modul für die Verundung der Antekdenz der Konklusion ist, dann ist $\frak{I}$ zwar eine Falsifikation für die zweite Prämisse und für alle vorkommenden Variablen definiert, aber keine Falsifikation von der Konklusion wie bereits oben erläutert.

Meine Frage wie kann ich zeigen, dass $\frak{I}(\psi)=1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything about "erweitern" in the statement of the lemma, so I'm not sure I understand the question, but let me describe the situation you focus on, where an interpretation $\mathfrak I$ falsifies the second premise. So $\mathfrak I$ must verify all the formulas in $\Gamma$, must verify $\theta$, and must falsify all the formulas in $\Delta$. Because $\mathfrak I$ verifies $\theta$, it also verifies $\psi\to\theta$, no matter what truth value it gives to $\psi$. So, since it verifies all the formulas in $\Gamma$, verifies $\psi\to\theta$, and falsifies all the formulas in $\Delta$, it falsifies the conclusion sequent.

An analogous argument shows that, if $\mathfrak I$ falsifies the first premise, then it falsifies $\psi$, verifies $\Gamma$, falsifies $\Delta$, therefore verifies $\psi\to\theta$, and falsifies the conclusion.

Conversely, if $\mathfrak I$ falsifies the conclusion, then it must verify $\Gamma$, falsify $\Delta$, and verify $\psi\to\theta$. The last of these means that$\mathfrak I$ either falsifies $\psi$ (thereby falsifying the first premise) or verifies $\theta$ (thereby falsifying the second premise).

Comment: one thing you said if $\vartheta$ is verified then $\psi\rightarrow \vartheta$ is also verified. But this is not true. If $\mathfrak{I}(\psi)=0$. But I have seen now that if if $\mathfrak{I}$ is a falsification of the second premise it can also be a falsification of the first premise or not. In first case we can use the analogous argument you mentioned, if it is not a falsification then $\mathfrak{I}(\psi)=1$ necessrily

Comment: If $\mathfrak I$ makes $\theta$ true then it also makes $\psi\to\theta$ true, regardless of the truth value that it gives $\psi$. Check the truth table of $\to$.